# How to get a percentage of total sales without huge subquery in SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I facing an issue of a way of calculating the total of the produced Amount column, so I can use it to calculate the 
(user sales amount/total users sales amount) percentage ratio

```
SELECT * FROM Sales

ID      Item    Amount
5       IS1     10.00
5       IS2     2.00
3       IS1     10.00
2       IS3     7.00
9       IS5     6.00

Example         35.00

DESIRED OUTPUT

ID      Amount  Percentage
5       12.00   34.28571%
3       10.00   28.57142%
2       7.00    20.00000%
9       6.00    17.14285%

Example 35.00   100.0000%

SELECT ID, SUM(Amount) AS Amount
FROM Sales
GROUP BY ID
```

I have seen various examples on stack and other forums where people are using an additional select to calculate the total of amount column as such

```
SELECT ID, SUM(Amount) AS Amount,(SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM Sales) AS Total, Amount/(SELECT SUM(Amount) FROM Sales)*100 AS Percentage 
FROM Sales
GROUP BY ID
```

But what do I do when my select query is huge, do you still put it in the select query or is there a better way this can be done.

```
SELECT a.ID, SUM(a.Amount) AS Amount, @rank:=@rank + 1 AS rank
FROM Sales a
INNER JOIN (SELECT @rank:=0) r
WHERE a.Item='IS1' 
AND a.tdate='2015-01-20'
GROUP BY a.ID
ORDER BY Amount
```

The original query is actually longer than this, because it is also pulling in descriptions and values from other tables.

Essentially the original code of what I am doing, is going to the Sales table, pulling in all user sales data by current day, by product, by product sub_id, by transaction id. Then ranking who sold the highest amount of product, on the day, of a particular transaction id.

Of course this code gets huge, so I am not sure if it is right to add this whole code again in SELECT query to calculate a total?

Is there no way, it can calculate the total of amount without doing another query?

Comment: And the answers are supposed to be valid for both MySQL and SQL Server, since you are using both products?

Comment: Hi I'd be happy if I could get it working for MySQL

Comment: If you provide a fiddle of your table it will be helpful for others to find solution.

Comment: Hi Mobasher, I just tried Jaques code in MSSQL and it worked perfectly, is there a MySQL equivelant of OVER PARTITION?

Comment: Tag properly!!!  MySQL <> SQL Server.  Which one is this???

Answer (score 0):

This will work on MSSQL, not sure about MySQL

```
Select distinct ID, SUM(AMOUNT) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) Amount, SUM(AMOUNT) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) / SUM(AMOUNT) OVER (PARTITION BY 1) * 100 Percentage
from Sales 
order by ID
```

It provides you with your Desired Output as shown above.

Comment: Do you know where you seen OVER PARTITION on MySQL, I can't find any resource to show that, as your method does indeed work on MSSQL. Now I need to find the equivilent for MySQL. I tried it, it didn't work in MySQL

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I scanned a page, and didn't realise that the prompt stated `SQL`. Here is a reference that might help
https://gist.github.com/kauragist/4208992

Comment: No problem thanks for helping. After doing more research it seems that doing something like this in MySQL is not possible without running an additonal query. Which might as well be the same thing as adding it into the select query

Answer (score 0):

I prefere a group by over a window function if it solves my problem:

```
SELECT a.ID, SUM(a.Amount) AS Amount, @rank:=@rank + 1 AS rank
  , s.SumAll Total
  , SUM(a.Amount)/s.SumAll*100 Percentage
FROM Sales a
, (SELECT @rank:=0) r
, (SELECT SUM(Amount) SumAll FROM Sales ) s
WHERE a.Item='IS1' 
AND a.tdate='2015-01-20'
GROUP BY a.ID
ORDER BY Amount
```

Assuming `sales` is in reality a rather expensive view, you'll maybe better of with that (asuming mysql likes window functions):

```
SELECT a.ID, SUM(a.Amount) AS Amount
  , @rank:=@rank + 1 AS rank
  , SUM(Amount) OVER (Partition By 1) Total
  , SUM(a.Amount)/SUM(Amount) OVER (Partition By 1)*100 Percentage
FROM Sales a
, (SELECT @rank:=0) r
WHERE a.Item='IS1' 
AND a.tdate='2015-01-20'
GROUP BY a.ID
ORDER BY Amount
```

Comment: Hi this type of code is exactly what I was raising my concern over. See how you have calculated the total sales. What do you do when that SELECT query is huge like some of the examples I gave above?

Comment: @adam gouldie i added a second option, but i dont think mysql supports it. you will need one subquery to calculate the total amount but not 2 as you've done in your original statement

Answer (score 0):

try

```
declare @total_amt as decimal(18,5)
set @total_amt=(select sum(isnull(AMOUNT,0)) from Sales)
select Id,AMOUNT,(SUM(Amount)/(@total_amt)*100) as Percentage from Sales group by Id
```

Answer (score 0):

This query produces the desired output without a sub query in MySQL. ***SUM(Amount) OVER ()*** gives you the total sum of Amount

```
SELECT ID, SUM(Amount) AS Amount,
       SUM(Amount)*100/SUM(Amount) OVER () AS percentage
FROM Sales
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: Can you please make this code formatted correctly? And possibly explain a bit why this solves the question, as that makes answers a lot more useful then purely code.